# How force Java app on IBM Cloud Foundry to use https connection

Tags: spring-boot, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I'm having some trouble forcing a Spring-Boot Java application on IBM Cloud Foundry to redirect/force all requests to a secure connection (https)

I'm using the java_buildpack

This is my peace of code where should block http request but is not blocking any http connections.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Value("${ENVIRONMENT:dev}")
private String ENVIRONMENT;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    if ("prod".equals(ENVIRONMENT)) {
        http.requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure();
    } else {
        http.requiresChannel().anyRequest();
    }
}
```

}

any idea?

Comment: Add more details on what you are doing. Are you talking about a custom domain or the default domain for Cloud Foundry apps. What is the code you are using for the http server, what its configuration?

Comment: Something common to all Cloud Foundry apps, they run behind multiple layers of reverse proxies. This is important for TLS termination because your client is not talking directly to your app & TLS is being terminated at one of the load balancers before your app. The net result is that if the request came in over HTTP or HTTPS needs to be determined by `x-forwarded-proto` or `x-forwarded-port` headers. The Java buildpack will set this up for you with Tomcat, but your mileage may vary with other servers. More details would help.

Comment: @DanielMikusa , thanks for your reply. So, do I need to protect each endpoint by checking the `x-forwarded-proto` and `x-forwarded-port`?

Comment: It depends. If you are deploying a WAR, the JBP will deploy Tomcat & configure it to do this automatically. You just use the standard Servlet methods for checking if the connection is secure. If you are using Spring Boot, Tomcat is embedded so see https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.5/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-behind-a-proxy-server. Other frameworks & languages, check their docs for something similar.